# Proper way to print out $$state promise?

Tags: javascript

This is what I get in return. As you see, `value` is `Resource` and it has what I need. Is there a proper to parse this?

[image]

This is what I get when I do `retVal.data`:

```
var retVal = vm.test.getData({ user_id: user_id }).$promise.then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

[image]

`JSON.parse(response)` is not an option either.

Comment: @Ty Q, why did you delete your comment? It worked!

Comment: @N-ate, don't do this. This is not how Promises should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `return` inside your `then` handler, but instead you should do things with the response there. There's no way to get the value back into the parent scope (in `retVal`).

Answer (score 0):

There was a user named `Ty Q` who gave me the right response. He removed his comment after that, but here's the worked one he suggested:

```
vm.test.getData({ user_id: user_id }).$promise.then((data) => console.log(data) );
```